# Creating a GUI for Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to create a GUI for this code that automatically downloads PDF's.  But I am not sure where to start. These are 2 inputs I need to change.

```
drp.select_by_visible_text('**Dan Pitts**')
checkfield=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="FieldCheckBox-**701847**"]')))
```

So just 2 input boxes and then have a submit button for it to open chrome and start.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time


driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('')

username=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]')
username.send_keys('')

password=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
password.send_keys('')

login=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/pcs-root/pcs-site-wrapper/div/div/div/div/pcs-                login/div/form/button')
login.click()

time.sleep(10)

driver.switch_to.frame('pcsIFrame')


growerlist=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="GrowerDropDownList"]')

drp=Select(growerlist)
drp.select_by_visible_text('**Dan Pitts**')

wait=WebDriverWait(driver,30)
getfields=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="GetFieldsButton"]')
getfields.click()

##time.sleep(4)
checkfield=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="FieldCheckBox-**701847**"]')))
checkfield.click()
```

Comment: Maybe check here: https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/thinkcspy/GUIandEventDrivenProgramming/02_standard_dialog_boxes.html

Answer (score 0):

I have put the two input boxes in and it does work for the Grower.  I cant seem to get it to work with xpath though.